Post not sending any console logs back and not sending data to mongoDB
I am creating a website where the user can create posts with certain values they need to fill out. Those values are determined on uploadPost.vue. Those values should be sent into the MongoDB database that I created but that isnt working either. I dont think its a major problem in something like app.js or main.js because my other feature, auth.js(login and signup) are working perfectly fine. They can send console logs and send data to the database, its just posts that doesnt work.
uploadPost.vue(component that holds most of the code, script only):
<script>
import Dialog from "primevue/dialog";
import FileUpload from "primevue/fileupload";
import { usePostStore } from '../stores/post';
export default {
  name: "uploadPost",
  components: {
    Dialog,
    FileUpload,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      petName: "",
      petAge: "",
      ownerName: "",
      phoneNumber: "",
      description: "",
      selectedAnimal: "",
      postImage: null,
      animalType: ["Dog", "Cat", "Monkey"], // Add more animal types as needed
      visible: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    acceptNumber() {
      var x = this.phoneNumber
        .replace(/\D/g, "")
        .match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
      this.phoneNumber = !x[2]
        ? x[1]
        : "(" + x[1] + ") " + x[2] + (x[3] ? "-" + x[3] : "");
    },
    handleFileUpload(event) {
      console.log("File selected: ", event.target.files[0]);
      this.postImage = event.target.files[0]; // Capture the file
    },
    async submitPost() {
      const postStore = usePostStore();
      await postStore.createPost(
        this.petName,
        this.petAge,
        this.ownerName,
        this.phoneNumber,
        this.description,
        this.selectedAnimal,
        this.postImage
      );
      this.visible = false;
      // Clear input fields after submission
      this.petName = "";
      this.petAge = "";
      this.ownerName = "";
      this.phoneNumber = "";
      this.description = "";
      this.selectedAnimal = "";
      this.postImage = "";
    }
  }
};
</script>

postController.js:
const userPosts = require("../Models/posts");
exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("Request Body: ", req.body);  // Log request body
    console.log("Uploaded File: ", req.file); // Log file upload

    const post = new userPosts({
      ...req.body,
      postImage: req.file.path
    });

    await post.save();
    console.log("Post saved: ", post); // Log the saved post
    res.json(post);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating post: ", error); // Log any errors
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};

posts.js(Models):
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const slugify = require("slugify");

const postSchema = new Schema({
  petName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  petAge: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  ownerName: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  postImage: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  animalType: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  slug: String,
});

postSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  if (!this.isModified("petName")) {
    next();
    return;
  }
  this.slug = slugify(this.petName, { lower: true });
  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("post", postSchema);

index.js(backend):
const express = require("express");
const router = new express.Router();
const profileController = require("../Controller/profileController");
const postController = require("../Controller/postController");
const authController = require("../Controller/authController");

router.post("/createProfile", profileController.createProfile);
router.patch("/updateProfile/:id", profileController.updateProfile);

router.post("/createPost", postController.createPost);
router.get("/posts", postController.getPost);
router.delete("/deletePost/:id", postController.deletePost);

router.post("/signup", authController.signup);
router.post("/login", authController.login);
router.get("/protected", authController.authCheck, authController.protected);

module.exports = router;

post.js(stores):
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const usePostStore = defineStore("post", {
  id: "post",
  state: () => {
    return {};
  },
  actions: {
    async createPost(
      petName,
      petAge,
      ownerName,
      phoneNumber,
      description,
      animalType,
      postImage
    ) {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/createPost", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            petName,
            petAge,
            ownerName,
            phoneNumber,
            description,
            animalType,
            postImage,
          }),
        });
        const post = await res.json();
        if (res.ok) {
          console.log("Post created: ", post);
          this.loadPost(post);
          console.log(post);
        } else {
          console.error("Error in response: ", post.error);
          throw new Error(post.error);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating post: ", error);
      }
    },

Sorry for so much code, just trying to give everything that could be helpful. I tried to add console.logs in multiple places to try and find the problem but none of them worked and the console continued to be empty when I filled out the values on uploadPost.vue. Im still a beginner on html and js so I am pretty lost on why it doesnt work. I thought it was a problem with routes but I can single out where any problem could be. Also, I am using two different ports: localhost:3000 for backend, and localhost:5173 for frontend. Please do let me know if any other code may be needed, any help will be appreciated thanks.

Can you check if the request being hit by checking the network tab of the browser and is the data is being passed in the payload of the request?

Hey man, sorry for the late reply. When i refresh the page, the network tab shows 53 requests. I see things like uploadPost.vue and post.js there, idk if I should be looking for anything specific. Although when I actually create a post, no requests are being added in the network tab, it stays at 53. Im guessing that means data isnt being passed?

If you don't see anything in the console means that the function is not called. Btw we are interested on the network call after you press the button that should submit it to the backend not really all the app in itself. Backend code is also irrelevant here because nothing is sent to the backend at this point.

Oh ok thanks that makes sense. So that means createPost() function isnt being called? If you dont mind me asking, how would I go about actually calling the function then? I already have a variable called usePostStore set to use any of those functions, would it be related to that?

Not sure exactly why it is not being called with all of this code. But it looks like you are lacking some await at some places. Try to fix that, try to put a simple button to remove possible bugs (see if just clicking on a button calls the functions properly), and maybe slap some ESlint on the whole project to check for any errors.

Im so sorry, had a busy day. I tried moving async createPost() into uploadPost.vue, and then doing the button strategy. Doing a simple:
"<button @click="createPost">Test".
This does send a request to the network as Post, but it is also saying 500 internal server error.

It also is finally sending some stuff to the console, although its mostly just my json errors that were inside the createPost function. One error says "POST http://localhost:3000/createPost 500 (Internal Server Error)" and its linked to the "const res = await fetch(link)" inside createPost. The others are the two console.errors I have inside createPost. Sorry if this is asking for too much, or asking  for direct help. Thank you so much already by the way, just seeing progress by seeing a request in that network tab show up already made my day.

Having an internal server error means either there is a connectivity issue, or server is not working. Try restarting the server, check the connection or you can try checking the logs for server.

Check the logs of the error 500 to understand why you have an issue there.
